# Change @media screen sizes in mobileangularui

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, mobile-angular-ui

I am just starting a project in **PhoneGap**, **Angular JS** and **mobileangularui**.

I am aware that mobileangularui uses bootstrap CSS and has components written in Angular JS. I am testing the responsive grid of bootstrap in my project.

The default screen sizes defined in bootstrap for breakpoints are:

- xs: 480px and up.
- sm: 768px and up.
- md: 992px and up.
- lg: 1280px and up.

I would like to change these to custom values. If I was using bootstrap (without mobileangularui), I would have customized the values [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/?id=a1b5f36484dd2346f1b7#media-queries-breakpoints) and downloaded the CSS. 
But, how do I make these changes in mobileangularui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `variables.less` in `<project-directory>\bower_components\bootstrap\less`.

Edit the following variable values:

```
@screen-xs:                  480px;
@screen-sm:                  768px;
@screen-md:                  992px;
@screen-lg:                  1200px;

@container-tablet:             (720px + @grid-gutter-width);
@container-desktop:            (940px + @grid-gutter-width);
@container-large-desktop:      (1140px + @grid-gutter-width);
```

Run `gulp build` again.

This will overwrite the app.min.css, responsive.min.css in your project with new screen size values.