# Bootstrap responsive grid not working with mobileangularui

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, mobile-angular-ui

I am trying out the responsive grid in bootstrap. I have created a project in Angular JS, mobile-angular-ui and phone gap.

In one of the html pages, I have the following code.

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Jane Doe</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">House 10, Street 8, City.</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">John Doe</div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">Apartment 10A, Blding XYZ, Block 10, City.</div>
</div>
```

I tried this out in screen sizes 320x480 (iPhone 4) and 768x1024 (iPad).
What I wanted to happen is:

- on the iphone's screen size, it should have shown a table with 1 column and 4 rows
- on iPad's screen size it should have shown a table with 2 columns and 2 rows.

However, the result is as the same for both:

iPad:

[image]

iPhone:

[image]

Desktop Browser:

[image]

How do I achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Did you include the [viewport tag](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile) in your document's head?

Comment: Yes, `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui, width=device-width"/>`.

Comment: `user-scalable=no` disables the responsive styles, so...

Comment: I just changed that to `yes` and the result is unfortunately the same.

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />` is what's recommended, as noted above. Is there a reason you're trying to constrain the viewport?

Comment: I am using `phonegap` and `mobileangularui`, and when i generated a new project in `mobileangularui`, the `index.html` was generated with these tags.

I tried the recommended tag, but the result is still the same. On the desktop resolution, the result is as I expect: 2 rows and 2 columns. Also, on the iphone's resolution it is what I expect: 4 rows and 1 column. But not on iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of testing with different permutations and combinations, we came to the conclusion that the `sm` screen size is getting ignored. Probably a [bug](https://github.com/mcasimir/mobile-angular-ui/issues/302) in mobile-angular-ui?

The responsiveness is working for the `xs` and `md` screen sizes. As I successively increase the screen size, the responsiveness jumps from `xs` to `md`.

So, I [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33824706/1237117) the default screen sizes in mobile-angular-ui as per my requirements and used only the `xs`, `md` and `lg` size classes.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">Jane Doe</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">House 10, Street 8, City.</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">John Doe</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">Apartment 10A, Blding XYZ, Block 10, City.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add this link in your head tag

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```